# ORM в Rails и как БД соединить с Rails приложением?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Здравствуйте, я хочу начать изучение MySQL и хочу учебник на русском языке и, было бы здорово, если бы там были бы ещё задачи. Так же интересует то, как происходит соединение БД с рельсовым приложением. Если можно, пожалуйста, объясните как можно проще и пошагово. Спасибо!

В комментариях написал, что Rails использует ORM. Вопрос исчерпан.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё очень просто:

- ставишь MySQL
- генерируешь приложение Rails
- в `Gemfile` добавляешь строку `gem 'mysql2'`, затем делаешь `bundle`
- в `config/database.yml` добавляешь следующее содержимое:

  `development:
    adapter: mysql2
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000
    database: <имя БД>
    username: <пользователь MySQL>
    password: <пароль от пользователя MySQL>
    host: localhost # хост, на котором висит MySQL`
- Затем выполняешь `rake db:create` для создания базы данных, указанной в конфиге.

Готово.

По поводу учебника, и прочего: если MySQL тебе нужен в связке с Rails, то прочитай [руководство по ActiveRecord(на русском)](http://rusrails.ru/active-record-query-interface). В 95% приложений на Rails 95% запросов делаются через ORM. Для остальных 5% нужно владеть языком SQL.

Пример [database.yml](https://gist.github.com/MAXOPKA/921dce5cd95996920358)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! 
Можно заполнение development  посмотреть на примере?

Comment: @basania добавил ссылку на пример конфига.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/193136/ обязательно почитайте про проектирование БД, чтобы не попадать в неприятные ситуации, когда вы уже полгода делаете проект,и вдруг оказывается что вы неправильно организовали бд и какие-то вещи сделать попросту невозможно без полного переделывания структуры бд и как следствие переписывания тонны запросов

Comment: @Darth спасибо большое за ссылку. Прочитаю обязательно сегодня-завтра.

Comment: Можно также почитать вывод `rails new --help` и вместо выпиливания SQLite сгенерировать приложение уже с настройками для MySQL -- разве что реквизиты проверить..

Comment: @D-side если есть приложение на SQLite, можно ли его перевести на MySQL?

Comment: @basania разумеется, выше как раз инструкции. Не совсем точные (скажем, содержимое database.yml лучше заменить указанным), но разобраться вполне можно.